# Redactor editor shows the videos instead of the link

Tags: redactor

Hi I am working on the redactor , when I paste the video link from the youtube in the redactor it shows the videos instead the link. how can avoid this ?.
I copied the link like this 
1) Right click on the video
2) Get video URL
3) Copy the URL
4) Paste in the Redactor.
 it shows the video instead the path or URL.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very old question, but for future reference:

Disable auto parsing of video links in the API, don't change the source files:
https://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/settings/autoparse/#s-autoparsevideo

Answer (score 0):

Hi I had just comment the convertVideoLinks() in the redactor.min.js file issue solved .